# Android path lineTo method with offsets instead of x, y cordinates

Tags: android, android-canvas

How can I make a new line by passing displacement values as opposed to passing x, y coordinates. For example if my last line ended at `x1`, `y1`, I'd like to do something like `path.lineTo(50, 50)` which would make a new line at `x1+50`, `y1+50`.

Comment: Make your own lineTo() for that.

Answer (score 1):

You already have a method for this in `Path`: [rLineTo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.html#rLineTo(float,%20float)).

```
public void rLineTo (float dx, float dy)
```

> Same as lineTo, but the coordinates are considered relative to the
>   last point on this contour. If there is no previous point, then a
>   moveTo(0,0) is inserted automatically.
>
> **Parameters**
>  **dx**  = The amount to add to the x-coordinate of the previous point on this contour, to specify a line
>  **dy**  = The amount to
>   add to the y-coordinate of the previous point on this contour, to
>   specify a line